JWT Bearer Flow for Passwordless Login on Community Site
I'm implementing one-time login (OTL) links for users on a community site to simplify the login process. We chose a “magic link” approach to support passwordless login for users who’ve had trouble with the standard login flow.
Here’s how we’re setting it up:

Connected App Setup: Created a connected app and self-signed certificate, ensuring that both the community and guest user profiles have access to the app.

JWT Bearer Flow: Using the OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Flow to generate a JWT for the connected app and specified username.

Token Exchange: Attempting to exchange the JWT for an access token via {community site URL}/services/oauth2/token.

Frontdoor Link: Planning to use the access token with frontdoor.jsp to initiate a session and grant community access.


Issue Summary
We’re encountering issues with steps 2 and 3, specifically with JWT creation and token exchange. Here’s what we have so far:

JWT Assembly: We use an Apex class to generate a compact serialization of Auth.JWS. When creating the Auth.JWT, we set:


Audience (aud) to the community URL (e.g.,
https://{instance}.sandbox.my.site.com/{site name})

Issuer (iss) to the connected app’s client ID

Subscriber (sub) to a community user’s username


We then use our self-signed certificate to create the Auth.JWT instance and return its serialized form.
Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt.toJSONString(), '{cert name here}');return
 jws.getCompactSerialization()


Token Exchange: In the same class, we have a function that POSTs to {community site URL}/services/oauth2/token with the following body where jwt is the result returned above :

String payload = 'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=' + jwt;

However, this call consistently returns "audience is invalid":
{"error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "audience is invalid"}

I understand that this error can result from various issues with the JWT. I'm curious if anyone else has experience with this or has successfully built a flow similar to this. I found a few threads where people had similar issues but everyone's problem was simply not putting the full community URL for the audience and token endpoint.

There's an out of the box solution for this - headless passwordless.  It sends a one-time code versus a magic link but with a bit of elbow grease, you can make it a link. (It uses codes vs links because UX research shows codes are easier to handle for people, esp. on mobile devices)

My concern with the headless password flow was that we need to completely control the look of all outbound customer-facing emails. In the case of the OTP, they state, "Depending on the verification method, Salesforce sends either an email or SMS text message with an OTP to the user." I worry that I won't be able to override that email/txt. I will look into it, though. Thank you!

SMS is a moving target, email can be changed - see docs.
